# How to select a particular column from a CSV in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I read a CSV file in Pyspark

```
inputRDD1 = sc.textFile('a.csv')
```

Data:

```
a b
1 1
2 3
```

I want to select the column'b' so that I can do manipulations on it like mean etc. But How do I select the column? I checked for many tutorials couldn't find one.

Please let me know,

Thank you.

i am trying to find the unique elements of a column.

I tried this:

```
newrdd = inputRDD1.map(lambda x: x[[2])
```

Not able to select the column 'b'

Comment: RDD is basically a parallelized collection like an Array (List in Python?) so you'd select the first element like how you'd do with Arrays except using RDD API. It'll be better to use Dataframe/Datasets API if you have a bunch of other stuff you want to do on the data apart from calculating average of each column. Also, mean and average are same ;)

Comment: i am trying to find the unique elements of a column.

I tried this:

newrdd = inputRDD1.map(lambda x: x[[1]) 

Not able to select the column 'b'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see raj's answer as it is more complete. I provided my solution as it might be easier to understand for a beginner.

`sc.textfile` reads the entire line and therefore there is only one column in your `inputRDD`. You will need to split your input lines first by your delimitation character(either a space or a tab). Once you have done that, you can select the relevant column you are after

```
inputRDD1 = sc.parallelize(['a b','1 1','2 3'])
newrdd = inputRDD1 .map(lambda x: x.split( )[1]) 
newrdd.collect()
```

gives

```
['b', '1', '3']
```

Comment: @jacob Thanks for telling what steps one needs to follow plus solution

Answer (score 2):

Hi to select a particular column from a RDD in Python, please do it like below

## Sample Data (tab seperated)

[image]

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

# creating spark context
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("SelectingColumn").setMaster("local[*]")
spark = SparkContext(conf = conf)

# calling data 
raw_data = spark.textFile("C:\\Users...\\SampleCsv.txt", 1)

# custom method to return column b data only
def parse_data(line):
    fields = line.split("\t")
    # use 0 for column 1, 2 for column 2 and so on
    return fields[1]

columnBdata = raw_data.map(parse_data)
print(columnBdata.take(4)) # yields column b data only
```

**Output ['b', '2', '7', '12']**